# Visual-studio style page navigation in Monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop

When I control-tab through open script files in MonoDevelop, I'd like it to emulate the behavior of Visual Studio.  That is, when I release control-tab, the next time I press control-tab it will take me to the first page I left.

For example, say I have documents A through Z.  I start on document A, hold control and tap 'tab' as it passes through B, C, D, E, F.  I then release control.  Now I press control again, tap 'tab', and the next page it displays is G.  What i WANT to happen is it displays A, because thats the page I was looking at previously.

This is how Visual Studio works and it makes it much easier to traverse your code.  Anyone know a way to make this work in Monodevelop?

Comment: What version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: Using 2.8.2, as comes with Unity.  I'm afraid to update further in case it breaks Unity.

Answer (score 0):

This feature works for me in version 2.8.8.4 running on my mac (10.5.8).

CHEERS